# Pipewire sound card hijacked by netns

Tags: linux, network-namespaces, pipewire

I sometimes run my browser in a VPN netns, like this:

```
sudo ip netns exec vpnns sudo -u myuser google-chrome &
```

This works great, except sometimes it seems that the netns "steals" the ability to use audio.

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and pipewire.

- `pavucontrol` in the main network namespace only shows `Dummy` under `Outputs`, and no input devices.
- `ip netns vpnns pids` shows nothing running inside the netns.
- `aplay -l` shows the output devices just fine.

I've tried `systemctl --user restart pipewire*`, but it doesn't seem to help.

How do I get the audio back into the main network namespace?